# Structuring Session Data in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, structure, scalability

This might be a bad title, but I was having trouble thinking of a good way to phrase my problem. Basically, I have a NodeJS application that has session management. Each session interacts with a set of data independent from the other sessions. I am having trouble coming up with a way to structure this in MongoDB. Things I have thought of:

Currently I'm storing a list of JSON "pages" that each have an ID corresponding to the session using it. I am almost positive this will not scale well though, because these "pages" will be read and updated frequently, so if I'm connected to Session1000, I'm going to have to search through 1000 items looking for the correct ID every time I update something from that session. If 1000 people are doing that roughly once a second, well...

Ideally I would like to store each session in a different collection, but the sessions need to be created and referenced dynamically, and I can't find a way in MongoDB to access a collection without hard-coding the name.

Hopefully this accurately describes my problem. Does anyone have any ideas to help me structure the db so that accessing/updating will give fast performance/scalability?